# uploaded image from next.js to django to store in aws s3 is blank

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework, next.js, boto3

I set up functionality for s3, I can easily upload images from Django admin interface. I have "createProduct" page and I want to create a product by sending form data from next.js. Django stores the URL s3 bucket in DB and retrieves the image from s3 when needed.

I set view image and cropping it functionality and it works as well. For this I have a separate component:

```
  <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="image">Image</label>
        <FileLoader 
          onFileUpload={image => setValue('image', image._id)}
        />
      </div>
```

I need to create an endpoint. Admin, first uploads the image, image gets saved to s3, then admin gets the url of the image, and passes it to the form data, so form data will be sent to the createProduct endpoint.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAdminUser])
def createProduct(request):
    user=request.user
    print("user in post",user)
    print("request.data",request.data)
    name=request.data['name']
    price=request.data['price']
    brand=request.data['brand']
    countInStock=request.data['countInStock']
    category=request.data['category']
    description=request.data['description']
    // Here i need to send the imag url I guess
    image=request.FILES.get('image')
    print("image",image)
    product=Product.objects.create(user=user, name=name,
                                   price=price,brand=brand,
                                   countInStock=countInStock,category=category,description=description, image=image)
    product.save()
    serializer=ProductSerializer(product, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

this is the endpoint for s3 upload:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def upload(request):
    data=request.data
    print("image data sent",data)
    client=boto3.client("s3",
                        aws_access_key_id=os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
                        aws_secret_access_key=os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
                        # s3 does not need region
                        # region_name=os.environ.get(AWS_REGION_NAME),
                        )

  response = client.upload_fileobj(data,"bingology-bucket","testing",{'ContentType': "image/jpeg"}
```

I get successfully uploaded message, image is in the bucket but it does show only black background and "type" is "-".

[image]

I also tried to get presigned-url, i got the url but it did not save anyting so s3. and I could not view the url when I visit due to permission issue even thought bucket is public

Comment: What's the specific issue you're having?

Comment: @juliomalves i could write the end point. all the tutorials or articles show how to set up the settings for s3 and upload from django admin

Comment: @juliomalves I forgot to edit the question to add endpoint

Answer (score 0):

I think we need another endpoint, with the logic to handle the upload using this architecture:

1. uploadImage (name for this another endpoint) receive image metadata from the next js.
2. uploadImage generates a pre-signed Url (since you are using S3), return this URL to nextjs and nextjs perform a upload using this presigned url and invoke the createProduct endpoint passing the URL (uploadImage can filter to return the exact URL of object) and all the product data to store in DB.

This approach can be better using a SAGA pattern to orchestrate things, because since you need to handle with 2 differently process (s3 upload and db transaction), you can orchastrate this things, or use transactions in a monolitic architeture (all business logic in one deployment).

Few tips:

Using SAGA pattern in this case, you just need to instrument a job to delete the image if has an error in createProduct. You can implement this by using a logic in the front end to put a message on an SNS with an lambda expression to read from this and delete the image in S3, since the product are not saved correctly.

Documentation:

https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html